# RSpec checking database field has a specific string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to ensure that when a user is created, the "measurement_units" field has the default string of imperial. When I test by creating a user I get the desired result, but when I test with my spec, I get `got: nil'

Any idea what I'm doing wrong in my spec?

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'cancan/matchers'

describe User do
    subject(:user) { User.new(email: 'test@test.com', password: '12345678', goal_id: '1', experience_level_id: '1', gender: 'female') }

  it "should be assigned measurement_units of imperial" do
    user.measurement_units.should eq("imperial") 
  end
end
```

The above test returns:

```
1) User should be assigned measurement_units of imperial
     Failure/Error: user.measurement_units.should eq("imperial")

       expected: "imperial"
            got: nil

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I know this is probably really basic, but I can't figure it out.

EDIT:

I assign the initial measurement_units in a before create filter on the user model like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

before_create :assign_initial_settings

def assign_initial_settings
  self.measurement_units = "imperial"
end
```

Comment: well where is the code that sets the default measurement unit?

Comment: Just updated the question with how I'm setting the measurement_units

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your callback is a `before_create`, but you're not actually calling User.create in your test - hence your callback is not getting run.

If you replace the `new` with `create` you should see the behaviour you expect.

Comment: That's causing all my tests to fail with the following: `RuntimeError:
       Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
`

Comment: My guess would be that this is because the record is failing validations -- probably you need a `password_confirmation`. Try `#create!` instead of `#create` and you'll know for sure.

Comment: Ohhh. I'm working on getting past that error right now. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll report back.

Comment: You were right about everything. Thanks for the help! Really appreciated!